# iAD not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iad

I have my interstitial ads set up in a way where if the user dies 4 times then a full page ads pops up. numberOfLoses increases everytime the player dies.

```
        numberOfLosses++
        if numberOfLosses == 4 {
            gameViewController?.showFullScreenAd()
            numberOfLosses = 0
        }
```

this works on the simulator and on my device the first time, but then i never see it working again, no matter how many times I die. Is this something that will work once its live on the app store or am i doing something wrong?

```
 func showFullScreenAd() {
        interstitial.delegate = self
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
        self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
}
```

if i println(self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()) i get false after the first time

here is my updated code (works but multiple ads being loaded at same time)

```
 //MARK: interstitial ad delegate

func showFullScreenAd() {
    viewForAd = UIView(frame: screenbounds)
    viewForAd.frame = CGRectOffset(viewForAd.frame, 0, screenbounds.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(viewForAd)

    iADInterstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
    iADInterstitial.delegate = self
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
    self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
}

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    iADInterstitial = nil
    println("did unload")

}

func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    viewForAd.removeFromSuperview()
    viewForAd = nil
    iADInterstitial = nil
    println("failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

}

func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    println("Ad did load")
    iADInterstitial.presentInView(viewForAd)
    UIView.beginAnimations("", context: nil)
    viewForAd.frame = CGRectOffset(viewForAd.frame, 0, -screenbounds.size.height)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations("", context: nil)
    viewForAd.frame = CGRectOffset(viewForAd.frame, 0, screenbounds.size.height)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
    println("action did finish")
}
```

Comment: On your phone/simulator, go to Settings>Developer. What's your iAd Fill Rate setting set to?

Comment: It's set to "always provide ad"

Comment: Are you setting `interstitial = nil` so that it can unload after the user dismisses the ad?

Comment: no should I be doing that? @DanielStorm can you show me how/where

Comment: @JeremySh check my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28652986/2108547). It's in Objective C but should help you determine what you need to do.

Comment: @DanielStorm again your code only works just the first time. im not getting any ads after that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `interstitial.delegate = self` (and whatever other code you've not shown that goes along with it.)

You only need two or three lines of code:

```
// Preloads an ad, so call on app startup (optional but recommended).
[UIViewController prepareInterstitialAds];

// Call once on your viewController when you create it.
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;

// Call when you want to show an ad (will show if one is available)
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

Thats all there is to the new methods in iOS 7.  Whatever other code you have may be causing problems so remove it, and if you still have problems (especially in test with 100% fill rate) then that needs further investigation.

Comment: this still only works the first time on device/simulator with 100% fill rate.

Comment: Just tested with all sorts of options, and it's very random.  I have a simple setup with the request call on a button click.  I can normally get 2 ads to show fairly quickly, but then it sometimes takes 10 minutes for another to show.  I've tried calling prepare each time and set the fill rate to 100% and "Unlimited Ad Presentation" on.  Tested on simulator, iOS 7, and iOS 8.  I just had it return "NO" from the present call but still present an Ad!  So I think it's a difficult one, will it work in live possibly not?

Comment: Anyone found more info on this?  According to the official docs it seems like you only need 2 lines of code.  The prepare call shouldn't even be needed because setting the policy to manual should start the initial fetch.  So what gives?  Something as simple as 2 lines of code... not working?  I'm seeing same thing, just 2 ads are shown, after that no more until I restart my app.